# Using SQLAzure for Session Data Works in Production but not Debug

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I have what feels like a very strange issue. I have a ASP.NET MVC5 project that is backed by SQL Azure for its sessions. This works perfectly when it's loaded into a Cloud Service on Azure. However when debugging it almost always throws the following exception on all loads after the initial page load (including subsequent calls for things like CSS files) until a new debugging session is started, then the first page works again but all subsequent pages break.

Message:

```
The connection is not of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.
```

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderUtilities.GetRequiredSqlConnection(DbConnection connection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) 
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
```

Target Site:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection GetRequiredSqlConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
```

I know it's not a connection being blocked by SQL Azure as the rest of the site uses the same database and connection string and is working fine to load the other data needed (plus it works on the first call to it).

Disabling using SQL Azure for sessions makes this all go away. But I need to place this site behind a load balancer so InProc session state no longer works.

Here's the sessionState from web.config

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

**Update:**

It was asked if I use transforms, and I do for the config file. And when switching to release and hitting run it does work fine (not in Chrome, but I assume that's some other issue). But it still bothers me because there's nothing in the Debug config file, and the only major change in the Release config is this line:

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

Comment: Are you by chance transforming your release configs differently then they are in debug mode?

Comment: I do, but session and database strings aren't changed between the two. But I just changed the build to release and now it works... So... ()&@*($

Comment: I'd inspect your web.config for any elements with Debug attributes, maybe you have some logging that's failing?

Comment: There's only one in the `compilation` tag in `system.web`. And the only time it breaks is using SQL for sessions. Debug + InProc sessions work fine.